# I've got an issue with ReactJS to download a file from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, download, mern

I need some help on an issue. I try to download a file on my client ReactJs from my server Nodejs.
I've got into my server.js :

```
router.route("/download/:filesaveas").get(function(req, res) {
  const fileLocation = "public/files/" + req.params.filesaveas;
  const file = req.params.filesaveas;
  res.download(fileLocation, file, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

When I try to download directly from the server http://localhost:4000/cww/download/testfile.pdf, the download works, I don't have any error and the file is not corrupted.

On my client side, I've got a function downloadFile which is called by a button "onclick" action.

```
import download from 'downloadjs'

downloadFile = (filetodownload) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/cww/download/'+filetodownload)
        .then(res => {
            var filename = "testfile.pdf"
            download(res.data, scriptname, "text/plain");
        });
     }
```

When I click on the button. Something is downloaded but the file seems to be corrupted. Impossible to open... I think, I've got a problem with the response data from the server.
By doing a console.log(res.data), I can see a part of my content PDF but with some strange
characters (like encoding) but impossible to have a correct file downloaded.

Please thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help ! I've just found my error !
I forgot to add ReponseType: blob and now it works perfectly ;-)

```
downloadFile = (filetodownload) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/cww/download/'+filetodownload, {responseType: 'blob'})
        .then(res => {
            var filename = "testfile.pdf"
            download(res.data, scriptname, "text/plain");
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want easiest option would be to open a new tab with that file's address which works only if route is public.

```
const newTab = false;
window.open('http://localhost:4000/cww/download/testfile.pdf',newTab ? '' : '_self' );
```

but you can do it without touching the file encoding or even use axios for this:

```
  onClick() {
    const fileName = 'testfile.pdf';
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/cww/download/testfile.pdf', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       // Security Headers if needed
      },
      body: undefined,
    })
      .then((data) => {
        return data.blob();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.size === 0) {
          throw new Error('File not found');
        }
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = fileURL;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        //  Error Action
      });
  }
```

Backend will simply stream the file to user.

I don't know much about res.download (might be better solution)

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

export async function getFile(request, response) {

  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('yourFileAddress', {});


  fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
    response.status(404).send();
    fileStream.removeAllListeners();
  });

  fileStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Streamed successfully to user');
    fileStream.removeAllListeners();
  });

  // finally starting the stream
  fileStream.pipe(response);

}
```